# Which functions can be represented as matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functions

I was reading the intuition for the associativity of matrix multiplication and it was given to be analogical to composition of functions. So which functions can be represented as matrices and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Finite dimensional) Linear transforms have matrix representations. These are maps $T:V \to W$ such that 
$$ T(cv_1) = cT(v_1) $$ and
$$ T(v_1+v_2) =T(v_1) + T(v_2) $$ 
for a constant $c$ and any $v_1, v_2 \in V$.

Since linear maps are special functions from one vector space to another, their compositions are associative just like  compositions of any functions.

Comment: Are linear transforms the only type of functions that have matrix representation or there might be others too? And is there any proof that such functions can be represented as matrices?

Comment: Yes to both questions.  To see that a matrix representation will work you can observe the image of the canonical basis vectors; these make up the columns of the matrix (if it acts by multiplication on the left).  To see that linear transformations are the only possible functions, check that matrix multiplication always respects the two defining properties of linearity.

Comment: For example, if $f:V \to W$ has the matrix representation $A$ (so that $f(v) = Av$), then we have $f(v_1 + v_2) = A(v_1 + v_2) = Av_1 + Av_2 = f(v_1) + f(v_2)$.  Similarly, $f(cv_1) = A(cv_1) = cAv_1 = cf(v_1)$. This proves $f$ must be linear. Any decent book on linear algebra will include full details.